# How to read and write on this file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a code that does the following:

Create a menu with three options.

1. Print the subjects
2. Search for a subject
   Q) Quit
   Create a main() function
   Prompt the user for a file name.
   Prompt the user for an option from the menu.
   Open the file and load the data into a list.
   Option 1 should print all the school subjects in the list, under a title

Once all the records have been processed, print a count.
Option 2 should allow the user to search for a subject in the list.
Add exception handling. (add last)
Create your own text file, with a list of 10 or more school subjects.
Submit the program module(s) and the output.
For a bonus, create a second module and import it, or add a menu item to add names to the list and save the data to a new file.

I keep getting "file not found" and was wondering if anyone could help. I want to name the read file as subjects.txt

This is the code I have written:

```
#Display menu and ask for user to select option
def menu():
    print('Enter "1" to print subjects')
    print('Enter "2" to search subjects')
    print('Enter "3" to add subject')
    print('Enter "q" to quit')
    option = input('Enter option: ')
    return option.lower()

#Reading files
def read_subjects(file_name):
    file1 = open(subjects, 'r')
    return file1.readlines()

#Add new subjects  
def write_to_file(file_name, subject):
    current_lines = []
    try:
        current_lines = read_subjects(file_name)
    except:
        pass
    current_lines.append(subject + '\n')
    file1 = open(file_name, 'w')
    file1.writelines(current_lines)
    file1.close() 

#Main function
def main():
    correct_file_name = False
    file_name = 'subjects'
    subjects = []
    # while loop to ensure a user selects an existing file with catch and try
    while not correct_file_name:
        file_name = input('Enter file name: ')
        try:
            subjects = read_subjects(subject)
            correct_file_name = True
        except:
            print('Error file not found')

    # while loop to implement contious flow of options
    while True:
        selected_option = menu()

        # quit program
        if selected_option == 'q':
            quit()

        # display subjects
        if selected_option == '1':
            print('Subjects')
            # Strips the newline character
            count = 0
            for line in subjects:
                count += 1
                print("{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
            print('Total subjects: ', count)
            print('==============================================')

        # search for a subject
        if selected_option == '2':
            subject = input('Search subject: ')
            print('Subjects')
            count = 0
            for line in subjects:
                striped_line = line.strip()
                if subject.lower() in striped_line.lower() or striped_line.lower() in hobby.lower():
                    count += 1
                    print("{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
            print('Total subjects: ', count)
            print('==============================================')

        # bonus add new hobbies
        if selected_option == '3':
            subject = input('Enter new hobby: ')
            write_to_file('subjects.txt', subject)

# call main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please condense your code down to a [mre] that reproduces _only_ the problem you are asking about. Remove irrelevant code such as asking the user for choices -- you can hardcode the user's choice if you must have it in your MRE. Also give the full traceback of the error you are asking about. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to SO!

Comment: Your `read_subjects` function takes a `file_name` argument, but doesn't use it.